# Javascript extending methods

Tags: javascript

The ***main.js*** has the following code

```
    APP.open = (function ($) {
    return {
      people: (function() {
        return {

          gender: function() {},

          age: function() {}
         }
       })()
     };
    }(jQuery));
```

and ***exteral.js*** has this:

```
    APP.open = (function ($) {
    return {
      people: (function() {
        return {
          race: function() {}
         }
       })()
     };
    }(jQuery));
```

***exteral.js*** is loaded last so is overwriting ***main.js***.

My question is, how should I write ***exteral.js*** in order to stop overwriting ***people*** method. I would like to extend `APP.open.people` method.

Comment: like as in you want the method in external to call the super (main.js) people as well as append its own code?

Comment: This is a good reading to learn how you should write your code to mimic inheritance in JS. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the specific method instead of replacing the entire `APP.open` namespace:

```
APP.open.people.race = function() {};
```

If you don't know which namespaces exist, add them first:

```
if (!'open' in APP) APP.open = {};
if (!'people' in App.open) App.open.people = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to stop appending to the jQuery as it is a bad programming habbit
2. You need to define your own space and use it for your code:

So the code will look like:

```
var LS = LS || {};
LS.open = function () {...}
```

and a call to it:

```
LS.open();
```

You can find more about JS modules [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

In your external.js you can try something like this:

```
var APP = APP || {}; 
APP.open.people = function(){return {race:function(){}}};
```